# What is the difference between signal and symbol in wireless communications?

Tags: signal, wireless, symbol

What are the definitions of signal and symbol in wireless communications, respectively? Often when I read books and papers I see things like "transmitted signal" and "transmitted symbol". Is there a difference? I tried searching online, but most results treat them as just words in English, not as concepts in wireless communications. I am new to this field and I'd appreciate any help.

---

For example, in the paper [*Beamforming Design for Large-Scale Antenna Arrays Using Deep Learning*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.03657) by Lin and Zhu, the words appear in the same paragraph introducing the system model:

> Let s denote the **transmitted symbol** with normalized average **symbol** energy,
>   i.e., E{|s|^2} = 1. The **symbol** is first multiplied by a scalar digital precoder v_{D}, and then by an Nt × 1 analog precoder v_{RF}, which is implemented using phase shifters. The final **precoded signal** is then given by x = v_{RF}v_{D}s.

Comment: Context: copy and paste some text where these are mentioned.

Comment: Question edited. @Andyaka

Comment: What type of modulation is being used - can you describe the final (precoded) signal and carrier? Maybe you have a picture?

Comment: @Andyaka I haven't read it through...I just randomly opened a file and searched for the two words. And honestly, the question in your comment is a lot more difficult than what I am asking...if I knew the answer to your comment I probably wouldn't need to ask the question in the first place. I included a link to the paper in the question, if you are interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A signal is a sequence of symbols transmitted sequentially over time.

A symbol is any distinct state of the communication channel.

For example, in a binary (two-state) channel, the states could be two voltage levels, two different values of current, or even two different frequencies — i.e., a simple modem. Such a channel can transmit one bit of information at a time.

Many types of channels can have more than two states, and this gives you the ability to transmit more than one bit at a time. For example, a 64-state channel can transmit 6 bits at a time, because 64 = 2<sup>6</sup>. We say that each symbol represents 6 bits, and the channel capacity is the symbol rate (also sometimes called baud rate) multiplied by the number of bits per symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any references, but from my experience and understanding, a **symbol is an information entity** of a signal and a **signal is the time-series of its information-associated symbols**.

E.g. you can have a digital signal of a communication system with symbol levels -1V, +3V and +10V. So each symbol has ternary values and the time-series of the symbols is the communication signal.