# What is 'Symbol' in communication?

Tags: communication, digital-communications

I am just asking about the meaning of "Symbol" in communication.
I know that I should search about it before asking, and that's what I did, but the issue is that I encountered many terms that I have never heard of, like modulation, PWM, PAM, bandwidth, etc.

I know well that the question is very obvious, but I spend almost one hour trying to understand its meaning. I am sorry about my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between signal and symbol in wireless communications?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494184/what-is-the-difference-between-signal-and-symbol-in-wireless-communications) See also [Synchronization in digital communication](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/561382/11683)

Comment: @DaveTweed Your *distinct state* definition is a better one than I'm seeing here. So I think your earlier answer is the better direct answer here. (When I think of symbols I immediately move to symbol space, mentally. Hypercubes with vertices representing symbols, both valid and invalid. This immediately allows thinking about error correction and the number of edge transitions (bit changes, so to speak) required to transition from one valid symbol vertex, to another.)

Comment: If you encounter terms you don't know, research them too. You might end up learning something.

Answer (score 3):

Symbol is the smallest amount of data the channel can carry.  On simple channels this is a single bit.

By using multi-level, parallel, multi-frequency, or multi-phase sigalling, or some combination EG: QAM you can get symbols that carry more than one bit.

Answer (score 2):

Lets use a simple, contrived example.

Say you have a serial data link running at 1 MHz, with a serial data line and an accompanying 1 MHz clock.  If the encoding scheme for the data is simple binary, 1 or 0, then the data rate of that interface is 1 Mbps.  You send 1 bit of information in every clock cycle.

Now let's say your interface can support 4 voltage levels.  Call these 4 voltage levels V0, V1, V2, and V3.  You then can use an encoder to map 2 consecutive bits into the 4 voltage levels, maybe as shown below:

00 = V0

01 = V1

10 = V2

11 = V3

Now, since you can send one of 4 voltage levels with each clock period, and each voltage levels is mapped to 2 bits, you have doubled the bit rate of your interface, to 2 Mbps, but using the same 1 MHz signally rate.

The complication comes in that the receiver has to be able to distinguish 4 voltage levels, instead of 2.  If the data channel is noisy, the receiver may not be able to do this effectively.  This is where SNR, or Signal to Noise Ration that Tony Stewart mentioned comes in.

So the 4 voltage levels, which carry 2 bits of information, is now called a symbol.  What I have just described is called PAM4

This process can be expanded using more voltage levels, and also by using the phase of the signal, which allows each symbol to carry more bits (4, 8, 16) etc.

Answer (score 1):

A symbol is a unique pattern of condensing multiple bits into fewer transitions with either 1 of multiple amplitudes and/or multiple phases in order to achieve compression of bandwidth required in bits/sec per Hz BW.

The tradeoff is a higher SNR required to achieve the same bit error rate according to Shannon-Hartley Law.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer.
I still cannot understand the exact meaning of symbol, I do understand that it is condensing multiple bits, but I don't understand what the transitions are, what bandwidth is, and why it is useful to compress bandwidth, is there any example that can illustrate these points?
Finally, what is SNR? and what is the bit error rate?

Comment: a symbol rate is also called baud rate which is the transition rate of compressed bits, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_rate

Answer (score 1):

It is really only practical to define symbol at first using examples. A typical digital bus uses a high voltage to send a digital "1" and a low voltage to send a digital "0". A clock signal tells the receiver when to sample the signal to see if it is a "1" or a "0".

Here, the symbol is is the voltage level, and it contains one bit of information. Since there is one bit per symbol, the data rate is the same as the clock rate. If the clock is 1 MHz, then the data rate is 1 megabit per second (Mbps).

But what if I design a fancier system where I have 4 different voltage levels? Low, medium-low, medium-high and high? Now, the symbol is still the voltage level, but each symbol contains two bits of information. So the data rate is 2x the symbol rate.

If the clock is 1 MHz, then the symbol rate is also 1 MHz and the data rate is 2 Mbps.

Now, what if I want to send the signal over a radio instead of a wire? Maybe I could use a frequency scheme. For example if I want to send a zero, I will use a frequency of 99.9 MHz and if I want to send a "1" I will use 100.1 MHz. So I can change the frequency back and forth from 99.9 MHz to 100.1 MHz to send my data out. Since there is no clock, the receiver will have to somehow figure out when the bit changes. But that is another topic for another day.

In this case, with the two frequencies, the symbol is the frequency. The symbol rate is nothing to do with the radio frequency. The symbol rate could still be 1 MHz, for example, if I change the frequency at up to 1 time per us.

I could extend this by picking 4 different frequencies to get 2 bits per symbol. Or even more frequencies.

There are many other ways to send data besides voltage and frequency. But when studying them, they tend to share concepts such as symbol rate, etc.

Bandwidth (in communications theory) is not directly related to data rate. But when two people are just talking casually to each other, sometimes they use bandwidth as a synonym for data rate. I don't want to try to define bandwidth now. But I hope you understand more about symbols from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is not present science explanations, just chat between students.
This is madness. It contains wrong similitude.

Think hearth pulse for a minute, let's say it beat 100 times/per minute.Let's assume it pumps 500ml of blood at each beat. It has a limit of each pulse cause limited veins, heart power, heart volume etc. That's bandwidth which every pulse's volume.

That's it at the symbol in communication. That's the tiny meaningful part which sends a tuple of bits in a beat. Bits just ones and zeros. If your communication system have broad way, you send more meaningful thing in a time if not you should split to many symbols them as the whole part of what you transmit. It's looks similar to bandwidth, but not.

Symbol not contains only your knowledge which have to send, but also it contains modulation knowledge and more and more things. Those parts make it a tiny, meaningful part of the communication.

Modulations just languages between transceiver and receiver.

Sometimes terms handles similar things but used for special things in communication.